# How can I make sure that tiles display properly when you first go to the page?

Tags: web-mapping, leaflet

This page is not showing my map tiles properly when you first go to the page.

http://bear.hol.low.li/Pocket_Docent/map.htm

If I resize the window it centers and distributes the tiles properly.

How can I make sure it tiles and refreshes correctly when the page first opens?

Comment: Can you turn the edit back into an answer, and mark it as "the answer" to allow this to be closed out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered:

I found out what was causing the problem. Jquery document.ready() was interfering with pageinit() in the body onload="pageinit();" call.

Delaying the map load by one frame makes the difference as suggested by this post:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leaflet-js/KVm6OvaOU3o/rflFy7bG8DkJ

(Having trouble making code show correctly in this venue. Please bear with me.

final code [

$(document).on('pageinit', '#map-page', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){  // set up the map to resize one frame after document.ready()

```
[ various map calls ]

    map.invalidateSize(); // refresh
}, 1);
```

});

]